# Multiple step MODEL rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, multi-step

I want to create an event by users using multiple steps for the creation. 
At the moment I have the following problem that it redirects to the first step after completing the second step.

The following is my controller

```
def new 
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  @user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { render :template => "events/new2" }
      format.json { render json: event_new2, status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def event_new2
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
      format.html { render :template => "events/new3" }
      # format.json { render json: event_new2, status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render action: "event_new2" }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

 # POST /events
 # POST /events.json
def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  @user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'event erfolgreich erstellt.' }
      format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My model requires only title and description to be present. 
The views are as follows:

Step1

```
<%= simple_form_for (@event), :method => 'new' do |f| %>  
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :title,:label => 'Event Titel' ,:placeholder=>"Titel des Events"%>
  <%= f.text_area :description,:label => 'Beschreibung',:placeholder=>"Beschreibung"%>
  <%= f.submit "Event erstellen", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right"%>
```

Step2

```
<%= simple_form_for (@event), :method => 'new' do |f| %>  
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :category%>
  <%= f.input :website, :label=>"Website"%>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is all of this routed? Could you post your routes?

Answer (score 0):

The normal one step method to create a model is for someone to go to the `new` page which will call the `new` controller and render the `new` page. The user fills in a form and hits submit which drives the `create` controller. If that works, it redirects to the `show` page.

If I were to do a two step creation, I would probably still go to the `new` page first and have it call the `create` action, but then rather than saving the model, I'd render the `step2` page and have them fill in more details and also include the first page of details in hidden fields. I would have that form call a different action than the first at which point I would save the model. Conversely, I could have the first form call the `step2` action then have that page call the `create` action. Another option is to save the model after step1 and retrieve it on step2. This option would be kind of ugly if step1 succeeds, but step2 fails.

Your `new` controller as it is will save a model to the database (without getting any user input) then render the `new2` page. I highly doubt this is what you want. If it is, I'd highly recommend against it.

I assume Step1 is what you render for `new2` and Step 2 is what you're rendering for `new3`. However, both of these forms as is will call the `update` controller (not shown). Also the method `new` is not standard, I'm a little surprised it didn't choke on it. Standard methods are `:get`, `:post`, `:put`, and `:delete`. You may be able to create non-standard one in your routes configuration, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you want to direct your form to your `new2` controller then you'll need to setup a route and use the `:url` option to `form_for` to get it there.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thx. that helped. i solved it all using the gem 'wicked'. works fine for me.